# pandas dataframe how to shift rows based on date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I am trying to assess the impact of a promotional campaign on our customers. The goal is to assess revenue from the point the promotion was offered. However promotion was offered for different customers at different points. How do I rearrange the data to `Month 0`, `Month 1`, `Month 2`, `Month 3`. `Month 0` being the month the customer first got the promotion.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? Please add your attempts in your question.

Answer (score 0):

With below self explanatory code you can get your desired output:

```
# Create DataFrame
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Account":[1,2,3,4,5,6],\
"May-18":[181,166,221,158,210,159],\
"Jun-18":[178,222,230,189,219,200],\
"Jul-18":[184,207,175,167,201,204],\
"Aug-18":[161,174,178,233,223,204],\
"Sep-18":[218,209,165,165,204,225],\
"Oct-18":[199,206,205,196,212,205],\
"Nov-18":[231,196,189,218,234,235],\
"Dec-18":[173,178,189,218,234,205],\
"Promotion Month":["Sep-18","Aug-18","Jul-18","May-18","Aug-18","Jun-18"]})
df = df.set_index("Account")
cols = ["May-18","Jun-18","Jul-18","Aug-18","Sep-18","Oct-18","Nov-18","Dec-18","Promotion Month"]
df = df[cols]

# Define function to select the four months after promotion
def selectMonths(row):
    cols = df.columns.to_list()
    colMonth0 = cols.index(row["Promotion Month"])
    colsOut = cols[colMonth0:colMonth0+4]
    out = pd.Series(row[colsOut].to_list())
    return out

# Apply the function and set the index and columns of output DataFrame
out = df.apply(selectMonths, axis=1)
out.index = df.index
out.columns=["Month 0","Month 1","Month 2","Month 3"]
```

Then the output you get is:

```
>>> out
         Month 0  Month 1  Month 2  Month 3
Account                                    
1            218      199      231      173
2            174      209      206      196
3            175      178      165      205
4            158      189      167      233
5            223      204      212      234
6            200      204      204      225
```